# Find strings from one text file in another

Tags: parsing, vbscript, split

Trying to loop through my `error.log` file and match strings in another `Map.log` (text) file.  I think I'm looping incorrectly as the script ends after it has matched the first line in the `error.log` file against each line in the other `Map.log` file.  After doing that, it should be moving to the next line in the `error.log` and comparing against all in `Map.log`, etc.

The reason I need to do this is the `error.log` file doesn't contain enough info to pinpoint the source of the problem, but it does contain the date and times.  I've been manually matching those up with the info in the `Map.log` file to see the specific cause, but there can be thousands of lines in the `Map.log` file. This would remedy that.  Basically, I want to match the date/time from error.log in `map.log` and pull out the corresponding "FcId: #". An ideal result would be:

```
3/14/2016 1:20:35 PM: FcId: 98766
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM: FcId: 46253
```

```
On Error Resume Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   

Set ERROR_logfilename = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\Error.log")
Set MAP_logfilename = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\Map.log")

'==============================
'This section pulls all of the date and time strings in the error.log file
'for matching in the maps.log file (everything before the first comma). 
Do While Not ERROR_logfilename.AtEndOfStream
  arrStr = Split(ERROR_logfilename.ReadLine, ",")
  strError = arrStr(0)
  '==============================
  Do While Not MAP_logfilename.AtEndOfStream
    strLogItem = MAP_logfilename.ReadLine

    If InStr(strLogItem, strError) Then
      WScript.Echo strLogItem
    End If
  Loop
Loop

ERROR_logfilename.Close
MAP_logfilename.Close
```

The `error.log` file contains lines like:

```
3/14/2016 1:20:35 PM,Warning in List.
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,Warning in List.
```

The `map.log` file contains lines like this:

```
3/14/2016 1:20:34 PM,key_id: 1 FcId: 987766 ac_id: 987763 prim_1_eftv_dttm: 8/11/2014 prim_2_eftv_dttm: 8/11/2014  
3/14/2016 1:20:34 PM,key_id: 1 FcId: 987766 svr_id: 2872158 br_FcId: 987764 eftv_dttm: 8/11/2014  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1470 btm_md_qty: 1551
3/14/2016 1:20:34 PM,Record count: 2
3/14/2016 1:20:34 PM,List.calcLength() Calculated :  FcId: 987766 currentDate: 8/11/2014 Length: 81 with 1 webo(s).
3/14/2016 1:20:35 PM,RESULT for FcId: 987766 GnId: 2585 lbrFcId:: 987764 SeqId: 1 Length: 81 Top: 1470 Btm: 1551 on Date: 8/11/2014
3/14/2016 1:20:35 PM,Date Range for completion: 987766 : 8/11/2014 12:00:00 AM - 3/14/2016 12:00:00 AM
3/14/2016 1:20:35 PM,Processed record: 11 Id: 987766
3/14/2016 1:20:35 PM,End: 
3/14/2016 1:20:35 PM,Begin: 
3/14/2016 1:20:36 PM,key_id: 1 FcId: 29910 ac_id: 29908 prim_1_eftv_dttm: 12/1/1998 prim_2_eftv_dttm: 12/1/1998  
3/14/2016 1:20:36 PM,key_id: 2 FcId: 29910 ac_id: 29908 prim_1_eftv_dttm: 10/1/2000 prim_2_eftv_dttm: 10/1/2000  
3/14/2016 1:20:36 PM,key_id: 1 FcId: 29910 svr_id: 350499 br_FcId: 29909 eftv_dttm: 12/1/1998  term_dttm: 10/1/2000  top_md_qty: 1270 btm_md_qty: 1350
3/14/2016 1:20:36 PM,key_id: 2 FcId: 29910 svr_id: 350500 br_FcId: 29909 eftv_dttm: 12/1/1998  term_dttm: 10/1/2000  top_md_qty: 1390 btm_md_qty: 1560
3/14/2016 1:20:36 PM,key_id: 3 FcId: 29910 svr_id: 350501 br_FcId: 29909 eftv_dttm: 12/1/1998  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1620 btm_md_qty: 1800
3/14/2016 1:20:36 PM,key_id: 4 FcId: 29910 svr_id: 350502 br_FcId: 29909 eftv_dttm: 12/1/1998  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1840 btm_md_qty: 2020
3/14/2016 1:20:36 PM,Record count: 2
3/14/2016 1:20:36 PM,List.calcLength() Calculated :  FcId: 29910 currentDate: 12/1/1998 Length: 750 with 1 webo(s).
3/14/2016 1:20:36 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 3997 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 1 Length: 82.51 Top: 1270 Btm: 1352.51 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2584 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 2 Length: 106.27 Top: 1352.51 Btm: 1458.78 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 3998 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 3 Length: 122.22 Top: 1458.78 Btm: 1581 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 3999 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 4 Length: 48.43 Top: 1581 Btm: 1629.43 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2588 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 5 Length: 76.06 Top: 1629.43 Btm: 1705.49 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2592 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 6 Length: 34.81 Top: 1705.49 Btm: 1740.3 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2594 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 7 Length: 16.43 Top: 1740.3 Btm: 1756.73 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2595 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 8 Length: 25.27 Top: 1756.73 Btm: 1782 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2597 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 9 Length: 43.5 Top: 1782 Btm: 1825.5 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2598 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 10 Length: 19.97 Top: 1825.5 Btm: 1845.47 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2599 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 11 Length: 19.53 Top: 1845.47 Btm: 1865 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2600 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 12 Length: 8.67 Top: 1865 Btm: 1873.67 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 4007 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 13 Length: 43.33 Top: 1873.67 Btm: 1917 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2603 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 14 Length: 45.24 Top: 1917 Btm: 1962.24 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2605 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 15 Length: 19.76 Top: 1962.24 Btm: 1982 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 3989 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 16 Length: 14.98 Top: 1982 Btm: 1996.98 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2607 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 17 Length: 15.82 Top: 1996.98 Btm: 2012.8 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 3990 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 18 Length: 7.2 Top: 2012.8 Btm: 2020 on Date: 12/1/1998
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,Date Range for completion: 29910 : 12/1/1998 12:00:00 AM - 10/1/2000 12:00:00 AM
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,Record count: 2
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,List.calcLength() Calculated :  FcId: 29910 currentDate: 10/1/2000 Length: 400 with 1 webo(s).
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 3999 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 1 Length: 9.43 Top: 1620 Btm: 1629.43 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2588 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 2 Length: 76.06 Top: 1629.43 Btm: 1705.49 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2592 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 3 Length: 34.81 Top: 1705.49 Btm: 1740.3 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2594 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 4 Length: 16.43 Top: 1740.3 Btm: 1756.73 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2595 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 5 Length: 25.27 Top: 1756.73 Btm: 1782 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2597 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 6 Length: 43.5 Top: 1782 Btm: 1825.5 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2598 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 7 Length: 19.97 Top: 1825.5 Btm: 1845.47 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2599 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 8 Length: 19.53 Top: 1845.47 Btm: 1865 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2600 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 9 Length: 8.67 Top: 1865 Btm: 1873.67 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:37 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 4007 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 10 Length: 43.33 Top: 1873.67 Btm: 1917 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2603 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 11 Length: 45.24 Top: 1917 Btm: 1962.24 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2605 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 12 Length: 19.76 Top: 1962.24 Btm: 1982 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 3989 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 13 Length: 14.98 Top: 1982 Btm: 1996.98 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 2607 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 14 Length: 15.82 Top: 1996.98 Btm: 2012.8 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,RESULT for FcId: 29910 GnId: 3990 lbrFcId:: 29909 SeqId: 15 Length: 7.2 Top: 2012.8 Btm: 2020 on Date: 10/1/2000
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,Date Range for completion: 29910 : 10/1/2000 12:00:00 AM - 3/14/2016 12:00:00 AM
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,Processed record: 12 Id: 29910
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,End: 
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,Begin: 
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,key_id: 1 FcId: 987765 ac_id: 987763 prim_1_eftv_dttm: 8/11/2014 prim_2_eftv_dttm: 8/11/2014  
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,key_id: 1 FcId: 987765 svr_id: 2872159 br_FcId: 987764 eftv_dttm: 8/11/2014  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1750 btm_md_qty: 1791
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,Record count: 2
3/14/2016 1:20:38 PM,List.calcLength() Calculated :  FcId: 987765 currentDate: 8/11/2014 Length: 41 with 1 webo(s).
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,RESULT for FcId: 987765 GnId: 2585 lbrFcId:: 987764 SeqId: 1 Length: 41 Top: 1750 Btm: 1791 on Date: 8/11/2014
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,Date Range for completion: 987765 : 8/11/2014 12:00:00 AM - 3/14/2016 12:00:00 AM
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,Processed record: 13 Id: 987765
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,End: 
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,Begin: 
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 1 FcId: 46253 ac_id: 46251 prim_1_eftv_dttm: 12/1/1991 prim_2_eftv_dttm: 12/1/1991  
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 2 FcId: 46253 ac_id: 46251 prim_1_eftv_dttm: 6/1/1998 prim_2_eftv_dttm: 6/1/1998  
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 1 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133009 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 890 btm_md_qty: 911
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 2 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133010 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 911 btm_md_qty: 968
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 3 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133011 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 968 btm_md_qty: 1036
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 4 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133013 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1036 btm_md_qty: 1070
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 5 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133015 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1090 btm_md_qty: 1120
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 6 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133017 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1120 btm_md_qty: 1172
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 7 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133018 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1172 btm_md_qty: 1220
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 8 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133021 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1240 btm_md_qty: 1320
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 9 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133024 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1320 btm_md_qty: 1380
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 10 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133026 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1400 btm_md_qty: 1430
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 11 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133027 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1430 btm_md_qty: 1450
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 12 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133030 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1450 btm_md_qty: 1510
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,key_id: 13 FcId: 46253 svr_id: 133031 br_FcId: 46252 eftv_dttm: 10/16/1991  term_dttm: 3/14/2016  top_md_qty: 1510 btm_md_qty: 1540
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,Record count: 2
3/14/2016 1:20:39 PM,List.calcLength() Calculated :  FcId: 46253 currentDate: 12/1/1991 Length: 650 with 1 webo(s).
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 2584 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 1 Length: 40.86 Top: 890 Btm: 930.86 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 3998 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 2 Length: 99.04 Top: 930.86 Btm: 1029.9 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 3999 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 3 Length: 55.1 Top: 1029.9 Btm: 1085 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 2588 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 4 Length: 81.13 Top: 1085 Btm: 1166.13 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 2592 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 5 Length: 59.17 Top: 1166.13 Btm: 1225.3 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 2594 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 6 Length: 62.35 Top: 1225.3 Btm: 1287.65 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 2597 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 7 Length: 141.25 Top: 1287.65 Btm: 1428.9 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 4007 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 8 Length: 15.7 Top: 1428.9 Btm: 1444.6 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 2603 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 9 Length: 54.36 Top: 1444.6 Btm: 1498.96 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 2605 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 10 Length: 29.7 Top: 1498.96 Btm: 1528.66 on Date: 12/1/1991
3/14/2016 1:20:40 PM,RESULT for FcId: 46253 GnId: 3989 lbrFcId:: 46252 SeqId: 11 Length: 11.34 Top: 1528.66 Btm: 1540 on Date: 12/1/1991
```

Comment: that is because your map file is already at the end of the stream.  You need to reset the map file to read it again.

Comment: That makes sense.  When you say "reset", how do I reset the loop?  Sounds like  "Do While Not MAP_logfilename.AtEndOfStream" is the problem.  Not quite sure how to make it restart from the top.  I'll investigate...  Maybe counting the lines in the error.log file and doing a for/next that many times....?

Comment: I would read the entire file into a string, split it on the line breaks and put that in an array.  Then you can just loop through the arrays to check.

Comment: Ok.  A newb at arrays.  I'll look into this, changing strLogItem = MAP_logfilename.ReadLine to strLogItem = MAP_logfilename.ReadAll I'm guessing, for starters.

Comment: Tried to use your suggestions.  Have a look and see if I'm implementing them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to adjust it so that it picks up the right line feed.

```
'===================================
On Error Resume Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ERROR_logfilename = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) & "\Error.log")
Set MAP_logfilename = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) & "\Map.log")


errorContents = Split(ERROR_logfilename.ReadAll, vbCrLf) 'get the contents and split on the line feed
mapContents = Split(MAP_logfilename.ReadAll, vbCrLf)

ERROR_logfilename.Close 'close the file
MAP_logfilename.Close

For i = 0 To UBound(errorContents) - 1 'loop through error log contents
    arrStr = Split(errorContents(i), ",")
    strError = arrStr(0)
    For j = 0 To UBound(mapContents) - 1 'loop through map log contents
        If InStr(mapContents(j), strError) Then
            wscript.echo strError & " " & strMap
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you.  Made some tweaks to suit my needs, but this example got me what I needed.  Thank you.  I'll post my final script.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final script I ended up with thanks to Sorceri's help.

```
'===================================
On Error Resume Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ERROR_logfilename = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) & "\Error.log")
Set MAP_logfilename = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) & "\Map.log")

strOutputFileName = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\Error_Clean.log"

        Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strOutputFileName, 2 , true) 'Clear old errors
        objFile.Write ""   
        objFile.Close

errorContents = Split(ERROR_logfilename.ReadAll, vbCrLf) 'get the contents and split on the line feed
mapContents = Split(MAP_logfilename.ReadAll, vbCrLf)

ERROR_logfilename.Close 'close the file
MAP_logfilename.Close

For i = 0 To UBound(errorContents) - 1 'loop through error log contents
    arrStr = Split(errorContents(i), ",")
    strError = arrStr(0)

    For j = 0 To UBound(mapContents) - 1 'loop through map log contents
        If InStr(mapContents(j), strError) and InStr(mapContents(j), "PM,Processed record: ") Then

    arrStr1 = Split(mapContents(j),"CmplId: ")
    strMapContents = arrStr1(1)

        'wscript.echo strError & vbCrlF & "Cmpl_Fac_ID: " & strMapContents
    CleanErrors = strError & vbCrlF & "Cmpl_Fac_ID: " & strMapContents & vbCrlF

        Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strOutputFileName, 8 , true) 'Write new errors
        objFile.WriteLine CleanErrors   
        objFile.Close

        End If

    Next 
Next 

'==================================
```